# Harry Potter fan fiction involving time travel and King Arthur

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a Harry Potter fanfic in which Harry goes to the past and is 5 or 7 years old. He is found and adopted by Merlin and is stuck in the past and is immortal until his time approaches. He becomes a healer and is adopted by quite a few people including Arthur Pendragon and Morgan le Fey.

Comment: This sounds like you're asking us to identify a specific fanfic, so I've edited the question to make that clearer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Not at all thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You might be thinking of Basilisk-born by Ebenbild. [Here's the link to the story](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10709411/1/Basilisk-born) The only thing is that he goes to the past as a 15-year old. Otherwise, it seems to match.